# Get stack of where TypeORM MySQL error was trigerred in NestJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm running many queries in the background at various intervals and I'm struggling to find out where this error is originating within my NestJS app. I just see its probably between the user and session tables. Its still only in development and happening maybe once or twice a day so its tough to debug and replicate.

There is a OneToMany relationship with session and users.

But manually going through the data with various queries I'm not picking up any irregularities.

How can I find the original line in the .ts where this TypeORM query is getting called? Is there some global setting I can turn on that would include this originating line and trace in the app code and not just the internal mysql module/drivers.

Thanks!

```
 /home/user/app/server/src/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222
[0]                                 new QueryFailedError(query, parameters, err),
[0]                                 ^
[0] QueryFailedError: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`app_db`.`session`, CONSTRAINT `FK_3d2f174ef04fb312fdebd0ddc53` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
[0]     at Query.onResult (/home/user/app/server/src/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222:33)
[0]     at Query.execute (/home/user/app/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:36:14)
[0]     at PoolConnection.handlePacket (/home/user/app/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
[0]     at PacketParser.onPacket (/home/user/app/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
[0]     at PacketParser.executeStart (/home/user/app/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
[0]     at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/app/server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
[0]     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
[0]     at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
[0]     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
[0]     at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
```

Comment: It's not in `MysqlQueryRunner.ts` line number `222`?

Comment: @FanoFN I mean the originating line in the NestJS app code. not the MySQL driver at the top of the trace